# Switch statement in dart with set expression

Tags: dart, set, switch-statement

Here is a simple dart program with a switch statement.

```
void main() {
  var list = [1, 2];
  var set = <int>{1, 2};
  var map = <int, int> {1: 2, 3: 4};
   
  switch (list) {
    case 1:
      print(1);
      break;
    case [1, 2]:
      print(2);
      break;
    case const <int> {1, 2}:
      print(3);
      break;
    case <int, int>{1: 2, 3: 4}:
      print(4);
      break;
  }
}
```

As I understand in the dart lang, the `switch` statement does not check `==` for every case, but rather it does pattern matching.

In the above code, when the expression is `switch(list)`, the console prints `2`. When it is `switch(set)`, the console does not print anything, and for `switch(map)`, the console prints `4`.

Questions:

1. Why when the expression is `switch(set)`, the switch does not print `3`?
2. Why `const` is required for `Set`, and not for `List` and `Map`?
   If I remove `const` in the set case, I get an error message :

> The expression of a constant pattern must be a valid constant.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Dart 3?  Is this a newly created project with a minsdk of >3?

Comment: Notice the `const` in front of the "Set pattern". That means that you're doing an equality check on a constant *value*, not using a pattern. If you wrote `const` in front of the other collection patterns, like `case const [1, 2]:` and `case const <int, int>{1: 2, 3: 4}:`, then they would also be comparing for equality (identity) of constant values, not doing any destructuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart supports the following types of patterns:

- [Logical-or](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#logical-or)
- [Logical-and](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#logical-and)
- [Relational](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#relational)
- [Cast](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#cast)
- [Null-check](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#null-check)
- [Null-assert](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#null-assert)
- [Constant](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#constant)
- [Variable](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#variable)
- [Identifier](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#identifier)
- [Parenthesized](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#parenthesized)
- [List](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#list)
- [Map](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#map)
- [Record](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#record)
- [Object](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#object)
- [Wildcard](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#wildcard)

Notice that both `List` and `Map` have built-in pattern types, while `Set` does not.

There is however a constant pattern, which allows for `case const <int> {1, 2}:`.

Also consider this:

```dart
void main() {
  print(const <int> {1, 2} == <int> {1, 2}); // false
  print(const <int> {1, 2} == const <int> {1, 2}); // true
}
```

So with that in mind, the following:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = [1, 2];
  var set = const <int>{1, 2}; // add const
  var map = <int, int> {1: 2, 3: 4};
   
  switch (set) {
    case 1:
      print(1);
      break;
    case [1, 2]:
      print(2);
      break;
    case const <int> {1, 2}:
      print(3);
      break;
    case <int, int>{1: 2, 3: 4}:
      print(4);
      break;
  }
}
```

prints `3`.